# Why external CustomViews have the red lock?

Tags: android, github, gradle, dependencies

I recently added [this](https://github.com/rey5137/material) GitHub repo in my Android Project, so I've proceed to add my gradle dependencies which looks like this:

```
dependencies {

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

And when I put a Custom View if I use one with the greenlock it's ok but when I put one with the redlock gives me the "Rendering Problems" error.

[image: Here is the image of How it looks when I select it from the Custom Views]

¿What Should I've do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything using that dependency.
We can take an example:

```
InternalEditText in EditText
```

This means that InternalEditText is an inner class of EditText. The red lock means that it's a private class, so the structure of EditText class is:

```
public class EditText {
    private class InternalEditText {

    }
}
```

So you can't access that class directly.

**Solutions**

- Reflection: not recommended if you can workaround the problem
- Fork of the project: you can create a fork of the project on GitHub and change those classes in public classes

Btw why do you want to use those inner private classes? That project is useful to use material widget on pre lollipop devices so for the EditText (for example) you can use `com.rey.material.widget.EditText`

Comment: I'll try to fork it, If it works; well you'll have my correct answer if not I'll do the same haha, thanks! :D